# Eclipse error- Can't complete the install because one or more required items couldn't be found

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Yesterday I updated Android SDK tool to 22.6.1. After update, Eclipse show the following error,

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above.  Current version is 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705.  Please update ADT to the latest version.
```

So I tried to update the ADT to latest version, but after a few seconds of checking I got a error like `Can't complete the install because one or more required items couldn't be found.` in the eclipse pop up.Following is the snapshot of the error,

[image]

Now I am unable to run any android project in the eclipse.Have anybody faced this kind of problem? Please let me know if you need any more information.

**Edit:**

I tried the following,

Changed `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

to

`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

then I got a error like

`Your original request has been modified.
 "Android DDMS" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue yesterday and I tried with the following way

instead of updating using the url with `http://` make `https://`

```
Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

with

```
Android Developer Tools Update Site - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

**EDIT:**

- Open your eclipse and go to `Help->Install New Software...`
- Choose the Work with Drop Down and select the ADT url previously you installed
- Change the `URL` `http://` with `https://`

you need to choose **Work with**: with Already installed URL and change to `https://`

**EDIT II:** you need to unchecked the `update sites during install to find required software`[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah I am doing these basic steps and then check `Developer Tools` then it searches for compatibility and shows me that error.

Comment: By the way, I am using `Eclipse Helios`.Is there any problem with that?